# Add value to textbox from sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a site just to learn ASP.NET c#. I am stuck though trying to get values from my database, i want to say if the "customer" is logged in that i can display his address details some textboxs. Similar to a sproc using Select. Could someone assist me or recommend where i can learn how to get details of customer IF they are logged in? Or is there a particular way i should do this and not use "bad programming methods".

Comment: Which platform are you using?

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** --- **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - but it is not a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using....

Answer (score 0):

Using The built-in Membership class is advised:

```
MembershipUser m = Membership.GetUser();

if (m == null)
{
   // User not logged on.
}
```

The User Id stored in `m.ProviderUserKey`, than if you are using [Entity Framwork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) (If you don't, consider using it. its simple and handy) fletch the data about this user using:

```
var loggedOnUser = context.Users.First(u=>u.ProviderUserKey == m.ProviderUserKey);

    if (loggedOnUser  == null)
    {
       // Shoudn't happen. If do, the user logged in for some reason is not stored in the database.
    }
```

Its better for you to implement CustomMembershipProvider and CustomMembershipUser derived from MembershipUser, so you can retrieve all the information about the user this way:

```
// Get custom user (if allready logged in)
CustomMembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser() as CustomMembershipUser;
```